# How to get the contents of a UItableView row on selection of a button in the row

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Table view which has a button and the label which contains some string value which is populated from an API call. I want to get the string in the label and pass it to another view controller whenever I select the button. How do I get the string values?

Comment: Don't get the string from the cell - get it from your data source. Use either protocol / delegate pattern or "callback closure". A little searching for `uitableviewcell button` will give you many, many answers, blogs, tutorials, etc, to help you find the best approach for your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have created a cell prototype with a label and a button, and you've connected the button to an `@IBAction` in your cell class, here is the "callback closure" approach:

```
class LabelAndButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!

    var myCallBack: (()->())?

    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        myCallBack?()
    }

}

class TestButtonCellTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var data: [String] = [
        "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
    ]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelAndButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! LabelAndButtonCell
        cell.theLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.myCallBack = {
            print("Button tapped for row: \(indexPath.row) - data: \(self.data[indexPath.row])")
            // do something
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `UITableViewDelegate`'s method `didSelectRowAt`

For this example I suppose you have an array of Strings that you're using to set the titles in `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let string = data[indexPath.row]
}    
    //In case your data list contains another object, 
//you access the string property the same way   
(let string = data[indexPath.row].name)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. This method gets the position of the button when it is tapped in order to get the cell from the tableView. Then grab the string you want and instantiate and push your next view controller.

```
func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    if indexPath != nil {
        cell = tableView.cellForRowAt(indexPath: indexPath)
        let myString = cell.label.text
        let nextVC = NextViewController.instance()
        nextVC.someString = myString
        navigationController.pushViewController(nextVc)
    }
}
```